# Creating a webapp in flask, generating a new html file in each request but flask returns the previous one

Tags: python, html, flask, bokeh

I am trying to build a web application in flask, and in one of the functions when you submit a form a Bokeh generates a .html file which include the plot.

The problem is once you submit the form the first gets displayed and everything works smoothly but when you hit the backward button or go back to home page you submit another form with new information still you will see the first plot.

I narrowed the problem down to this line

def plot():
    return render_template("stocks.html")

so when I check in templates folder the new .html file including new plot with new request information is there but flask renders the previous .html

```
import os
import numpy as np
import requests

import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect, url_for
import datetime



app_STMilestone = Flask(__name__)



colors = ["navy", "green", "purple", "red"]
prTypes = ["Adj_Open","Adj_High", "Adj_Low", "Adj_Close"]
cmdict={}
cmdict["HD"] = "Home Depot"
cmdict["DIS"] = "The Walt Disney Company"
cmdict["MSFT"]="Microsoft Corporation"
cmdict["BA"]="The Boeing Company" 

os.environ["API.i"] = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/"
os.environ["API.ii"] = "?start_date="
os.environ["API.iii"] = "&end_date="
os.environ["API.iv"] = "&api_key=<snip>"



@app_STMilestone.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])
def index_lulu():
    stocks ={}
    prtype =[]
    if request.method == "GET":

        return render_template("Page1.html")

    else:
        Company = request.form.get("Company")
        stDate = request.form.get("stdate")
        endDate = request.form.get("enddate")


        for i in prTypes:
            if request.form.__contains__(i):
                prtype.append(request.form.get(i))





        stDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(stDate,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(endDate,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        if stDate >= endDate :
            return redirect("/error")
        else:
            r = requests.get(os.environ["API.i"]+Company+os.environ["API.ii"]+stDate+os.environ["API.iii"]+endDate+os.environ["API.iv"])
            data =r.json() 
            db = pd.DataFrame(data["dataset"]["data"], columns=data["dataset"]["column_names"])


            # prepare some data
            for i in prtype:
                stocks[i] = np.array(db[i])


            dates = np.array(db['Date'], dtype=np.datetime64)



            # output to static HTML file
            output_file("templates/stocks.html", title="stocks")

            # create a new plot with a a datetime axis type
            p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=350, x_axis_type="datetime")

            # add renderers
            j=0
            for i in prtype:
                if j > 3 : 
                    j = 0
                p.line(dates, stocks[i], color=colors[j], legend=i)
                j+=1

            # NEW: customize by setting attributes
            p.title.text = cmdict[Company]+" stock prices From "+stDate +" to "+endDate 
            p.legend.location = "top_left"
            p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0
            p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
            p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'
            p.ygrid.band_fill_color = "olive"
            p.ygrid.band_fill_alpha = 0.1
            save(p)
            return redirect(url_for("plot"))



@app_STMilestone.route("/plot")
def plot():
    return render_template("stocks.html")



@app_STMilestone.route("/error", methods=["GET","POST"])
def error():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("error.html")
    else:
        return redirect("/")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_STMilestone.run(debug=False)
```

Comment: Try clearing the cache,cookies for your browser and retry.

Comment: @amanb Already did not working. I think its a flask bug. I moved around it by embedding a plot in my own html template

Comment: Try to narrow your problem by replacing API calls with a local dummy data, then convert and minimise your code so it can be run by other that can help you. Thanks!